# Execve '/bin/sleep' command freezing

Tags: c, process, background, exec, freeze

I have a client server program where the server is a simple shell

commands are working fine, arguments are being passed fine, but I think execve is freezing

so here's the simple shell code -- the first half os to verify if the command is allowed in this shell

```
  while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE)) != 0){ //loop until connection has been terminated
      if (!strcmp(buf, "quit\n")){
        printf("User %s disconnected.\n", username);
        flag1 = 0; //the user will need to login again
      }
      if (flag1 == 1){ //the user is loged in
        bg = p3parseline(buf, argv_for_shell);
        strtok(buf, "\n");
        printf("User %s sent the command '%s' to be executed.\n", username, buf);
        // temp = argv_for_shell[0];
        // strcat(temp, "\n");
    //check if the command is allowed
    flag2 = 0; //set command allowed? flag back to false
    file = Fopen("rrshcommands.txt", "r");
    while (Fgets(command, MAXLINE, file) != NULL){
      strtok(command, "\n");
      if (!strcmp(argv_for_shell[0], command)){
        flag2 = 1;
      }
    }
    Fclose(file);

    if (flag2 == 0){ //case where the command is not allowed
      printf("The command '%s' is not allowed.\n", buf);
      strcpy(buf, "Command not allowed\n");
      Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
    }
    else{
      if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {   /* Child runs user job */
        printf("Fork/Execing the command %s on behalf of the user.\n", argv_for_shell[0]);
        Dup2(connfd, 1);

        if (execve(argv_for_shell[0], argv_for_shell, environ) < 0) {
          printf("%s: Command not found.\n", argv_for_shell[0]);
          exit(0);
        }
        printf("Finished execing\n");
      }
      /* Parent waits for foreground job to terminate */
      if (!bg) {
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
          unix_error("waitfg: waitpid error");
        memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf)); //flush the buffer
        Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
      }
      else{
        memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf)); //flush the buffer
        Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
      }
      signal(SIGCHLD, reap_background);
    }
  }
```

I posted a question previously that was related to this, but was caused by a separate issue -- feel free to read through that one as well

I added a printf statement below the execve to confirm if the program was getting to that point, and it isn't

the output of the shell looks like

```
User k logging in from 127.0.0.1 at TCP port 1024.
User k successfully logged in.
User k sent the command '/bin/sleep 1&' to be executed.
Fork/Execing the command /bin/sleep on behalf of the user.
```

any ideas?

Comment: the function: `execve()` never returns, unless the creation of the new process fails.   The posted code seems to expect the call to `execve()` to return as a normal operation.

Comment: this kind of line pair: `memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf)); //flush the buffer
        Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));`   seems a bit 'odd' as the array buf[] is set to all NUL bytes, then calling `RioWriten()` using `strlen(buf)` but `strlen(buf)` will return 0, so trying to write 0 bytes.   However my research <http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ch10-preview.pdf> indicates 1) the spelling: `rio_writen()` not `RioWriten(),  so where are you getting the alternate spelling?

Comment: where is `bg` being set?  perhaps the user entered command needs to be parsed a bit more to find the trailing `&` to set the `bg` variable.

Comment: from the man page for `waitpid()`, note the following: "In the case of a terminated child, performing a wait  allows
       the  system  to  release  the resources associated with the child; if a
       wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains in a  "zombie"
       state (see NOTES below)."  Therefore, the posted code can create 'zombies'.  probably not what you want.

Comment: @user3629249 that why I have the signal handler, and bg is being set correctly

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected as far as I can see. First you `fork()`, then you print "Fork/Execing the command /bin/sleep on behalf of the user.", then you call `execve()`. The call to `execve()` will never return (assuming it succeeded) as `execve()` replace the current program.

Therefore this line:

```
printf("Finished execing\n");
```

will never be reached.

This is precisely why you (presumably) did the `fork()` in the first place. What you should be doing is `wait()`ing for the `fork()`'d process to complete.

Also, what is this line for?

```
signal(SIGCHLD, reap_background);
```

Comment: but I do wait in the next if statement.does this need to be moved?

Comment: Right, but you don't print anything after that, so the output you pasted was what was expected.

Comment: interesting that you say that because gdb shows the line `if (!bg)` and then it freezes. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `bg` set to? Debugging `fork()` with gdb is non-trivial. Read this link: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Comment: bg is set to 1 -- as it should

Comment: I placed a print statement after the child block and before if `if(!bg)` and it printed. I placed on inside the last else statement, and it printed out. gdb isn't letting me go that far so I'm in the dark of what's causing this. Any ideas? all other commands are working, even when I run them in the background... WHAT IS THIS? lol

Comment: found the solution, turns out I didn't need to write back to the client for the client to read the stdout redirection